# Python RegEx Replacement

Tags: python, regex, python-re

The goal is to replace the hex digits between the quotes following "apple=" with new random hex digits. There will be multiple occurrences of the pattern and they will all need to be replaced with different new random hex numbers.

```
import re
import secrets

with open("C:/Users/Name/Downloads/demo.txt", 'r') as file:
    file_data = file.read()

pattern = re.compile(r'apple="................"')

matches = pattern.finditer(file_data)

for match in matches:
    hex_replacement = secrets.token_hex(8)
    # code that replaces the old hex number (the one in between the quotes following apple= indicated by the periods) with "hex_replacement"

#code that saves new file to replace old file
```

Comment: Is the random hex string always the same length and is the length known in advance ? Can you provide a sample of the data ?

Answer (score 1):

Given the information above, this is the regex I came up with `r'(?<=apple=")[0-9a-f]{16}(?=")'`, it's made of three sections:

- `(?<=apple=")` positive lookbehind, checks `apple="`
- `[0-9a-fA-F]{16}` match 16 hexadecimal values, lowercase or uppercase
- `(?=")` positive lookahead, check `"`

Then, [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#re.sub) and therefore [`re.Pattern.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#re.Pattern.sub) allow the `repl` argument to be a function, so I created a function that returns 16 hexadecimals from secrets (also do you really need secrets and not random ?).

All together, this is what I have.

```py
import re
import secrets
from io import StringIO

buf = StringIO(
    """\
apple="0123456789abcdef"
apple="0123456789abcdef" apple="0123456789abcdef"
apple="0123456789abcdef" banana="0123456789abcdef"
"""
)


def randhex(match) -> str:
    return secrets.token_hex(8)


pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=apple=")[0-9a-fA-F]{16}(?=")')

with buf as fh:
    file_data = fh.read()

new_data = pattern.sub(randhex, file_data)

# or with anomymous lambda with one discarded argument
new_data = pattern.sub(lambda _: secrets.token_hex(8), file_data)

print(new_data)
```

NB. I used a [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=bytesio#io.StringIO) to avoid creating a file, but since you have a file continue using `with open(...) as fh:`.